# hit counter with php and mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm tring to make a simple php visit counter... i write this code

```
<?php

$Connect = mysql_connect('Localhost','root','');
$Database = mysql_select_db("myDatabaseName");
$CurrentVisit = mysql_query("SELECT visit FROM myWebsite");

$NewVisit = $CurrentVisit+1;
$UpdateField = mysql_query("UPDATE myWebsite SET visit = '$NewVisit'");
echo $NewVisit;

?>
```

When i execute this code the outpout is "5". Why? Where is the error? In my database i created an int(11) field call visit. i'm running this script on localhost.

Comment: Why should this code do anything else? For example, `mysql_query` returns a resource and not the number of current visits

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to fetch result row. `mysql_query` function returns result resource, not row values.

You can use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) function.

```
$Connect = mysql_connect('Localhost','root','');
$Database = mysql_select_db("myDatabaseName");
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT visit FROM myWebsite");

$CurrentVisit = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result["visit"]);

$NewVisit = $CurrentVisit+1;
$UpdateField = mysql_query("UPDATE myWebsite SET visit = '$NewVisit'");
echo $NewVisit;
```

If you don't need old counter value in your code (for some other manipulations) and you just need to increment database value, you can run just 
`UPDATE myWebsite SET visit = visit+1` query as Jelle Ferwerda suggested.

**P.S.:** Do not use `mysql_` extension cause it is deprecated. Use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`Mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: I do not understand why you have to use mysql_fetch_array. I want to retrieve only ONE field from the database.

Comment: Because `mysql_query` returns result resource, not row values. You need to use `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` even in oreder to retrieve just one field.

Comment: I'm executing your code but always return "1" and the fields is empty

Comment: Your code assumes you have one value already insterted in your `myWebsite` table

Answer (score 0):

After you run the query you have to run something like mysql_fetch_array. However, you can just update your counter in the database by running

```
UPDATE myWebsite SET visit = visit+1
```

assuming you do not need to show the number. This would save you a query.

More logical imhop would be to just use google analytics?

Comment: Instead of Google Analytics I'd suggest using [Piwik](http://piwik.org/), an open source alternative.

Comment: I don't use Google Analytics because i prefer to create my OWN counter, to learn how to do things alone, with my competences.

Comment: OK, that is fine. Justr for the fun of it, check the offered counters online. You would save a lot of time, and get a lot more out of your counter by using a pre-build one. Time which you can then use building the rest of the site ;D

Answer (score 0):

You missed to fetch result from result set.first fetch data like this:

```
$CurrentVisit = mysql_fetch_array($Result['visit']);
```